# Calculate $\int_{C(0,1)} z^3\exp(\frac{1}{z^2})dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate: $$\int_{C(0,1)} z^3\exp(\frac{1}{z^2})dz$$
I don't have idea what I can do to use Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: What is $C(0,1)$?

Comment: Assuming $C(0,1)$ is the unit circle: If $f(z)=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$ then $\int_{C(0,1)}f(z)\,dz=2\pi i a_{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that $C(0,1)$ means $\{z \in \mathbb C: |z|=1\}.$

We have

$$z^3\exp\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)= z^3+z+\frac{1}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{z^3}+ .....$$

All summands on the RHS have anti-derivatives, with the exception $\frac{1}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{z}$.

Hence

$$\int_{C(0,1)} z^3\exp\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)dz= \frac{1}{2} \int_{C(0,1)}\frac{1}{z} dz=i \pi.$$